How to use different list in each DataTable column
I am using flutter datatable.
My table has two columns: name and address.
I want to use two different lists for each column.
Currently, I can only use one list for both columns which does not make sense.
Could you please advise.
Thank You
My code is:
Widget myTable = Container(
                      child: SizedBox(height: 500,
                      child: DataTable(columns: [DataColumn(label:
                      Text('Name')),DataColumn(label: Text('Address'))],
                      rows: List<DataRow>.of(myList)))
                   );


what is the use cases for using different lists?

please inform us what you try to achieve like 'expected result' and 'actual result'

I need to use different data for each table column. The statement below uses one list for both columns, in this example: rows: List.of(myList). I need to find a way to use a different list in each column.

If you have two List of data for each column, with the sample code below, you can show them in the related column:
class CustomTable extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTable({super.key});

  final nameList = const ['John', 'Doe', 'Smith', 'Alex', 'Max'];
  final addressList = const ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'India'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return myTable();
  }

  Widget myTable() => SizedBox(
        height: 500,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Address')),
          ],
          rows: List.generate(
            nameList.length,
            (index) => DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text(nameList[index])),
              DataCell(Text(addressList[index])),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

rows property in DataTable widget is responsible to render each row complemtly which contains different DataCell that every DataCell will render each column value in each row.
So if you have two or more list of value for your columns you can handle it in this structure like the sample code above.
If you expect more, feel free to leave comment and I would be happy to provide new code for you.
